# write subdatasets to hdf

Tags: gdal, hdf

Using gdal, it is possible to obtain the subdatasets contained in a hdf file, using the function:

```
datasource.GetSubDatasets()
```

Is it also possible to assign subdatasets to the file using gdal, i.e. a command like:

```
datasource.SetSubDatasets()
```

If not, what is the best way to create this type of file with multiple data sets?